# rails.vim in ubuntu error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

Disabling rails.vim: autoload/rails.vim is missing

code in ~/.vimrc

```
 set nocompatible
 syntax on
 filetype plugin indent on
```

why just me for the question diff google result?

Comment: It sounds like you are missing the file rails.vim inside ~/.vim/autoload . I would recommend reinstalling the rails.vim script and ensure that you unpack all the files correctly. I don't follow the last sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off to install [pathogen.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) following the README there. Then you can follow the installation instructions for [rails.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails) and everything will work correctly.

I really love how straightforward vim is.

Comment: Hooray for pathogen.  Total game changer for so many vim users.

Comment: I love it, this and vimballs.